# $M/aM\rightarrow N/aN$ surjective implies $N/N'/a(N/N')$ is zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I found the following statement in a problem sheet which I don't know how to approach. This is the following:
If $u:M \rightarrow N$ is an $A$-module homomorphism and we denote $N'$ the image of $u$. We let $a$ an ideal of $A$ and we assume that the induced map for $\bar u:M/aM\rightarrow N/aN$ is surjective it then the statement is that  $N/N'/a(N/N')$
is the zero module. This is supposed to be obvious but I don't how to approach it.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show that $\operatorname{Im}\bar u=(N'+aN)/aN$?

Can you show that $N/N'/a(N/N')=N/(N'+aN)$? (Actually it's enough to notice that $a(N/N')=(N'+aN)/N'$.)

Comment: yeah got it thanks